# How to Visualize the Safety_Lidar/Depth camera data on RViz from Docker Container

Tags: ros, docker-swarm, robotics, docker-container

I am currently collaborating with a mobile robot, as depicted in Image 1.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlRKW.jpg)

The robot is equipped with two sick_safety scanners, positioned at the front and rear. The data nodes/topics are publishing from a Docker container. To access the robot's PC, I utilize SSH by entering 'ssh username@ip.' Once inside the container, I can see the topic, and echoing the topic displays the raw text data.

I attempted two different approaches to visualize the data on rviz:

Approach 1:
I opened rviz from within the container, enabling me to view the rostopic list. However, upon attempting to open rviz, an error message appeared: 'qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0' (refer to Image 2).

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oKpd.jpg)

Approach 2:
I configured the IP addresses of both the robot PC and my PC. The robot was connected to a wifi-router via LAN, while my PC was connected via Wi-Fi on the same network (refer to Image 3).
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgss.jpg)

Although I could see all the topics on my PC, running rviz did not display any data; there was no TF data, and the Fixed Frame option was not available (refer to Image 4).
[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo4Wi.jpg)

Looking ahead, if I plan to integrate a RealSense camera with the robot, how can I visualize the camera data on rviz, whether on the robot's pc (GUI Tool) or my PC's?

Thank you.